# Can you use IDX indexes with xBaseJ

Tags: java, dbf, xbase

I have DBF's with IDX index files. It looks like xbase itself can handle them, but it does not look like a class has been written in xbasej for it yet. Has anyone used IDX files with xbasej, or can it be done?

Reference to xbase:
http://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/idx_comp.html

Comment: Do you know if these are compact index files, or the original ones?

Comment: I believe they are the original ones, I can use something like vi to look at them and it has legible data in them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [DBF#useIndex](http://xbasej.sourceforge.net/api/org/xBaseJ/DBF.html#useIndex(java.lang.String)) in xBaseJ?

Comment: Yes, but that looks to only handle NDX type indexes. My IDX indexes can not be used with the useIndex method. There is an NDX.java in xBaseJ, but there is not one for IDX's.